# Windows 7 with VS2008, Mobile Device Emulator Not Working

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-7, mobile

I have a windows mobile app developed under windows XP / Visual Studio 2008.

When I try and run it on windows 7 through visual studio I cant get the emulator to connect to the internet.

Other posts on the web have suggested windows 7 / VS2008 dosn't work for mobile device emulation. Is this true?

Comment: Could do but would rather not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I didn't have the Mobile Device Center installed on my Windows 7 machine. This is needed for the emulator to work.